# On a css margin-top: -10%, what is that percentage based off?

Tags: css, margin

I'm trying to figure out what is the percentage of a negative css margin.

```css
.box1 {
  border:1px solid red;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
}

.box2 {
   border:1px solid blue;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: -1%;
}

.box3 {
   border:1px solid green;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: -17px
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">2</div>
  <div class="box3">3</div>
</div>
```

So box2 & box3 flow out of box1 container, both are exactly aligned. I can't figure out what is the box1 negative percentage value based off ?

Answer (score 2):

It's based on the actual **width  of the parent element**. For example, here in your snippet (which is 600px wide and where the parent spans the full width), 1% becomes 6px, 2% become 12px etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the margin is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

In your case the parent block doesn't have width, so that take viewport width, so 1% it's big. If you reduce the window you will see the box2 move, you can also add width to box1 to understand.